# Finding the interval in which $a$ lies

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

> **Question**
>
> If $x\in \mathbb{R}$, the numbers $5^{1+x}+5^{1-x},\frac{a}{2},25^{x}+25^{-x}$ form an Arithmetic Progression, then $a$ must lie in the interval:
>
> (A) $[1,5]$
>
> (B) $[2,5]$
>
> (C) $[5,12]$
>
> (D) $[12,\infty)$

**My Approach**

Since the numbers $5^{1+x}+5^{1-x},\frac{a}{2},25^{x}+25^{-x}$ form an Arithmetic Progression,

$\implies a=5^{1+x}+5^{1-x}+25^{x}+25^{-x}$

$\implies a=5^{1+x}+5^{1-x}+5^{2x}+5^{-2x}$

After this, I am unable to find the range of $a$ to determine in which interval it lies. Usually to determine range, I use to either draw the graph of the function or equate the function to $y$, i.e., $y=f(x)$ then express $x$ as a function of $y$. The range of the original function then would be the domain of the new function $x=g(y)$. Here I am unable to determine the range by these methods.

Could you please help how to proceed or is there any alternative approach for this problem?

Kindly clarify my doubt.

Comment: Hint: $a(x) = 5y(x) + \frac{5}{y(x)}  + (y(x))^2 + (\frac{1}{y(x)})^2$ Now we have that $y(x)$ can be any positive number. So just find the possible values of RHS, to get possible interval of LHS. Or more "guessing" way: plug in $0$ and some other value to know the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

> For lower bound use $$x+y\geq 2\sqrt{xy}$$ if $x,y$ are positive. Notice that we get an equality iff $x=y$.

So $$5^{1+x}+ 5^{1-x} \geq 2\sqrt{5^{1+x} 5^{1-x} } = 10$$ with equality iff $5^{1+x}= 5^{1-x}$ i.e. $x=0$.

And similary for other two...

Since $\lim_{x\to \infty} 25^x =\infty$ we see $a$ has no upper bound.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How to determine the upper bound?

Comment: @Intellex There isn't one which can be seen by taking $x\to\pm\infty$.

Comment: @PeterForeman, Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that
$$a=10\cosh{(\ln{(5)}x)}+2\cosh{(2\ln{(5)}x)}$$
which has a minimum exactly when $x=0$ and both hyperbolic cosines are equal to $1$. Thus we have
$$a\ge12\implies a\in[12,\infty)$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am unable to understand your answer because I do not know about "hyperbolic cosines". Is that university level mathematics concept? I have just completed my high school.

Comment: I'm surprised you did not study [hyperbolic trigonometric functions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function) in high school. I use here the definition of the function $\cosh{(x)}=\frac12(e^x+e^{-x})$ and the fact that $\cosh{(x)}\ge1$.

Comment: Well, I did not to...

Comment: Sorry, actually I am used to terms like $cos^{-1}$ and inverse circular functions in place of $cosh$ and hyperbolic trigonometric functions. But may I know how did you express a as such functions?

Comment: Note that$$a=10\left(\frac12\left(e^{\ln{(5)}x}+e^{-\ln{(5)}x}\right)\right)+2\left(\frac12\left(e^{2\ln{(5)}x}+e^{-2\ln{(5)}x}\right)\right)$$and the definition of the hyperbolic cosine is given in my previous comment.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. I saw the link and noticed hyperbolic functions are different from inverse circular functions. Now I understood your step.

Answer (score 1):

$$2\cdot \dfrac a2=5\left(b^2+\dfrac1{b^2}\right)+b^4+\dfrac1{b^4}=5\left(b^2+\dfrac1{b^2}\right)+\left(b^2+\dfrac1{b^2}\right)^2-2$$ where $b^2=5^x>0,25^x=(5^2)^x=(5^x)^2=b^4$

$$a=\left(b^2+\dfrac1{b^2}+\dfrac52\right)^2-2-\left(\dfrac52\right)^2$$

Now $b^2+\dfrac1{b^2}=\left(b-\dfrac1b\right)^2+2\ge2$

$$\implies a\ge\left(2+\dfrac52\right)^2-2-\left(\dfrac52\right)^2=2+10$$